# Enforce access rights on Feathers.js resources

Tags: feathersjs

How restrict access access to a subset of a resource exposed via Feathers.js?

For example, how would you restrict CRUD operations to a user's tenantId or groupId?

So far, I have this somewhat working with a service hook.  The code below works for "get/find" but not for "put/update".  Tracing the resulting mongo query, only "_id" is being queried during "update" scenario.  It seems my query is being ignored or overwritten.

```
// my-resource.hooks.js
module.exports = {
    before: {
        all: [
            function(hook) {
                const userGroupId = hook.params.userGroupId; 
                // NOTE: userGroupId gets extracted via an Express js hook from auth/header

                hook.params.query = {
                    ...hook.params.query,
                    userGroupId 
                }
                return hook;
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

#### UPDATE

So far, I've extended the feathers-mongoose service implementation and update this bit of code. Seems to do the trick, but I'm still wondering if I'm missing something.

```
_get(id, params = {}) {
    params.query = params.query || {};

    const discriminator = (params.query || {})[this.discriminatorKey] || this.discriminatorKey;
    const model = this.discriminators[discriminator] || this.Model;
    let modelQuery = model
        .findOne({
            [this.id]: id,
            ...params.query
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to know if the user is allowed to modify an individual resource the best way is to retrieve it first, check the permissions and throw a [Feathers error](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/errors.html) if they are not allowed:

```
const errors = require('feathers-errors');

// my-resource.hooks.js
module.exports = {
  before: {
    all: [
      function(hook) {
        // NOTE: userGroupId gets extracted via an Express js hook from auth/header
        const userGroupId = hook.params.userGroupId;

        // If there is an id, get the entry first to check the permission
        if(hook.id !== undefined && hook.id !== null) {
          return hook.service.get(hook.id).then(entry => {
            if(entry.userGroupId !== userGroupId) {
              throw new errors.Forbidden('You are not allowed to access  this');
            }

            return hook;
          });
        }  

        // Otherwise just restrict the query
        hook.params.query = {
            ...hook.params.query,
            userGroupId 
        }

        return Promise.resolve(hook);
      }
    ]
  }
}
```